# Remove a pin which added on image dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove an image element if clicked, which is added dynamically using jquery.
The achievement is a simple pinned map like image app.

HTML:

```
<div class="imageMapContainer" style="position:relative;" >
    <img class="imageMap" src="image.jpg" style="position:relative;" width="300px" height="300px" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".imageMap").click(function(e){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var posLeft = e.clientX - offset.left;
    var posTop = e.clientY - offset.top;

    var pin = "<img onClick='javascript:removePin();' class='imgPin' src='pin.png'" + "style='width:auto;height:auto;position:absolute;left:" + posLeft + ";top:" + posTop + ";' />";
    $(".imageMapContainer").append(pin);    
});

function removePin(){
    //couldn't figure out here
}
```

I've tried a lot of things but, not a talented jscript guy I am I guess.
thanks in advance.

Comment: @putvande nope, not working ):

Comment: See my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: inline `onClick` w/ jQuery around? No please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your click event you can add `this` to send a reference to the clicked element.
You can than use that reference in your `removePin` function like:

```
$(".imageMap").click(function (e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var posLeft = e.clientX - offset.left;
    var posTop = e.clientY - offset.top;

    var pin = "<img onClick='javascript:removePin(this);' class='imgPin' src='pin.png'" + "style='width:auto;height:auto;position:absolute;left:" + posLeft + ";top:" + posTop + ";' />";
    $(".imageMapContainer").append(pin);
});

function removePin(elm) {
    $(elm).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.on`

```
$('.imageMapContainer').on('click', '.imgPin', function() { 
     $(this).remove(); 
});
```

Comment: does that only removes the one that I clicked, or all of the pins with imgPin class?

Comment: only the one which you have clicked.